# CALL cannot be submitted in multi-statement request

Tags: teradata

I need to call a stored procedure multiple times with different parameters at every call ...

So I have created a macro having definition like below to perform the desired operation.
However, it seems macro can not contain a multi statement request.
So is there any work-around available to have these multiple calls in macro ? Or can a stored procedure be a good option for this operation ?

Please advise.

Thank you !

```
CREATE MACRO m_Snapshot AS
(
CALL sp_Test('A',0);
CALL sp_Test('B',0);
CALL sp_Test('C',0);
);
```

Comment: Does the stored procedure contain DDL statements?

Comment: @xenodevil yes. It contains delete & insert statement along with cursor.

Comment: What I meant was Create/Drop type statements

Comment: You can't CALL an SP within a Multi Statement Request and a Macro is the same as a MSR.. But you can CALL any number from an SP, so nest them within another SP.

Comment: *It contains delete & insert statement along with cursor* This sounds very bad, can you explain what you're actually trying to do (or show the SP source)?

Comment: @xenodevil, my mistake :/ dint read it properly. No it do not contains Create/Drop DDL statements but the DML ...

Comment: @dnoeth I understand, but can not share the code ... policies ... the stored procedure contains two simple statements. One is delete & other is update single table. The filter values in the statements are derived from the Cursor logic. BTW, let me also try using SP ...